# Hibernate Errors ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: hibernate, eclipse-neon

**Error i'm getting is**

```
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at hibernate.example.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:28)
    at hibernate.example.storeProduct.AddProduct(storeProduct.java:20)
    at hibernate.example.storeProduct.main(storeProduct.java:13)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE
    at org.jboss.logging.Log4jLogger.translate(Log4jLogger.java:64)
    at org.jboss.logging.Log4jLogger.doLog(Log4jLogger.java:44)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.trace(Logger.java:107)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.registerStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:53)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorBuilder.addDialect(StrategySelectorBuilder.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorBuilder.addDialects(StrategySelectorBuilder.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorBuilder.buildSelector(StrategySelectorBuilder.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.<init>(AnnotationConfiguration.java:87)
    at hibernate.example.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:24)
    ... 2 more
```

**MY CODE IS HERE**

```
package hibernate.example;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;  
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;  
import org.hibernate.Transaction;  


public class storeProduct {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
{  
    AddProduct("Pents", "GUCCI BRAND", 500, 30, "PATA NAI");
}
public static void AddProduct(String pName, String pDes, double price, int items, String Brand) //      Access by Admin
{
    SessionFactory factory=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session=factory.openSession();  
    //creating transaction object  
    Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();  
    product p = new product();
    p.setpName(pName);
    p.setpDescription(pDes);
    p.setPrice(price);
    p.setItemsAvailable(items);
    p.setBrand(Brand);
    session.persist(p);
    t.commit();//transaction is committed  
    if ( session.isOpen() ) session.close(); 
    System.out.println("Product successfully Inserted to db");
}
```

**Product.java class**

```
package hibernate.example;

public class product {
private int pId;
private String pName;
private String pDescription;
private double price;
private int itemsAvailable;
private String Brand;

public product() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public String getBrand() {
    return Brand;
}
public void setBrand(String brand) {
    Brand = brand;
}
public int getItemsAvailable() {
    return itemsAvailable;
}
public void setItemsAvailable(int itemsAvailable) {
    this.itemsAvailable = itemsAvailable;
}
public int getpId() {
    return pId;
}
public void setpId(int pId) {
    this.pId = pId;
}
public String getpName() {
    return pName;
}
public void setpName(String pName) {
    this.pName = pName;
}
public String getpDescription() {
    return pDescription;
}
public void setpDescription(String pDescription) {
    this.pDescription = pDescription;
}
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

}
```

**HibernateUtil.java CLASS**

```
package hibernate.example;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
/**
 * Hibernate Utility class with a convenient method to get Session Factory object.
 *
 * @author Ali Hassan
 */
public class HibernateUtil {
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
static {
try {
    // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
    // config file.
    sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Log the exception. 
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

**product.hbm.xml FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="hibernate.example.product" table="product">  


<id name="pId"
    column="pId" 
    unsaved-value="0"
    >  
     <generator class="native"></generator>  
    </id>
    <property name="pName"></property>  
    <property name="Brand"></property>  
    <property name="price"></property>  
    <property name="itemsAvailable"></property>  
    <property name="pDescription"></property>               


 </class>  


</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Hibernate.cfg.xml file**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  
<hibernate-configuration>  
    <session-factory>  
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>  
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shoping</property>  
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>  
    <property name="connection.password">tiger</property>  
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>  
    <mapping resource="product.hbm.xml"/>  
    </session-factory>  

</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am fed up with this error. Getting the same error since 2 days. Not even a single solution works. I'm using ECLIPSE NEON. Include all the jars [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIbTw.png). I'm using hibernation in web project. The same files runs in other project with the same jars.

Comment: Is your "hibernate.cfg.xml" file is in intended path please verify

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `log4J 1.2.12` or higher.

You can check for conflicting version of class `org.apache.log4j.Level` in your classpath and try to resolve it. The TRACE level is available in the log4j jar of version 1.2.12 or higher, but you are using 1.2.11 and hence the problem.

Comment: Can you please mention the jars need to include.

Comment: You have used log4J_1.2.11 so please remove this and use upper version greater than >1.2.11

Answer (score 0):

Replace HibernateUtil file with below code: -

`package` com.mkyong.persistence;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

```
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void shutdown() {
    // Close caches and connection pools
    getSessionFactory().close();
}
```

}